# How to get pyautogui's click working on mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, ios-ui-automation, pyautogui

pyautogui's click method's issue:
I am running the script from Spyder, if I click anything on Spyder's window the click works fine.

If I execute a script to open Outlook, then click on anything, the click does not happen. Although I am able to use the "moveTo" functionality properly.

Things I have tried as suggested by doing google search:

```
pyautogui.click()
pyautogui.click()
```

OS : mac os high sierra

Note:
In order to reach any located image I have to do coordinates/2, as it is a Retina 2x display.

Any workaround or any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To anyone who might stumble into the same issue on a Mac, I was able to get it working by using a workaround that is using the pynput library.

Code:

```
import pyautogui
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller

mouse = Controller()
pyautogui.moveTo(x,y)
mouse.click(Button.left)
```

Answer (score 2):

OS X Mojave, the following works for me:

```
    pyautogui.moveTo(pos)
    pyautogui.dragTo(button='left')
```

`pyautogui.click()` throws an attribute error but `pyautogui.dragTo()` works instead.

Answer (score 2):

I just found out that in mac setting, I did not check the tip in front of PyCharm in privacy setting. After doing that, my pyautogui.click() function works.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue, Here is what I tried :

Just add one more line  `pyautogui.dragTo()` to focus on that particular selected area:

```
pyautogui.moveTo(990,28)
pyautogui.dragTo() 
pyautogui.click()
```