# Not able to auto click on a mac using python

Tags: python, macos, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui
import time

pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.click(pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(
    '/Users/USER/Desktop/Coding/Python/Tools/Personal/Auto Sign-in/searchBar.png')
```

I'm trying to make a script that logs into my school's portal automatically, this is just the start of the script. The `pyautogui.click()` doesn't seem to work on mac. It probably has something to do with their security measures. I gave VSC accessibility access in settings and the problem still persists. Any ideas?

Comment: have you already verified every other part of your program is correct, i.e. you are sure that macos is the point of failure?

Comment: You gave vscode accessibility? Why not actually Python, the program running the code?

Comment: @cricket_007 VScode is the program I hit the run button in, Python also has accessibility enabled.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco I made a program that only clicks and it doesn't work, don't know if they'res much more I can do to narrow down the problem.

Comment: My point is that vscode just does `python script.py`. You could do the same in the terminal to debug the issue

Comment: @cricket_007 a lot of other people had this issue on mac and enabling accessibility seemed to fix their issue. It shows that the program ran with no issue in the vscode terminal. I created a test.py that is just a click function and i tried to run it through the mac terminal and it said it couldn't find it even though i cd'd into the folder.

Comment: @iHildy your program may be short, but there are still multiple possibilities for what could be going wrong. My point was it is unclear if you are *assuming* that the problem is definitely macos related, or if you have verified that.  For example, have you tested this code on other operating systems?  Are you sure that pyautogui is correctly installed for your system?

Comment: I tried on my windows machine and worked fine. All other autogui commands work perfectly, it's just this one that doesn't.

Comment: It seems there is another similar question where someone has found a workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58066712/how-to-get-pyautoguis-click-working-on-mac do you have any problems with this approach?

Comment: @HymnsForDisco I tried the answer on there and it says it was unable to import pynput.mouse

Comment: @ihildy you must ensure you have installed the pynput package. "Unable to import" usually means that the module doesn't exist, i.e. you need to install it

Comment: @HymnsForDisco it shows that all requirements are already satisfied.