# PyAutoGUI doesn't want to click but can move

Tags: python, ui-automation, pyautogui

there was a question similar to this ([Why pyautogui click not actually clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52406707/why-pyautogui-click-not-actually-clicking)) but this didnt work for me. I have given pycharm (what I'm using) accessibility privileges but it still doesn't work :( here is my code:

```
import pyautogui, time
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.moveTo(235, 135, duration=1)
pyautogui.click()
time.sleep(0.1)
pyautogui.click(clicks=3, interval=0.1)
```

Comment: It worked for me on PyCharm after granting accessibility privileges on a MacOS Catalina. Can you give some details about your system?

Comment: its Catalina 10.15.4

Comment: Have you tried looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58087573/10763533)?

Comment: yes, this is actually the first module I tried to use for doing this. I have even tried to combine them like in that answer but it doesn't work

Comment: it manages to click on the window but then when I try to get it to click a button it does nothing

Comment: how have you managed to get it to work?

Comment: It works fine for me (so the code is good), but I'm not sure how to help I'm afraid.

Comment: it's pyautogui bug mine is also not working!

Comment: are you sure your delays enough? Try to icrease sleep time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pyautogui.click() didn't work for me either
I worked around it by using the mouse down and mouse up options...

```
pyautogui.mouseDown(button='left')
pyautogui.mouseUp(button='left')
```

just for convenience I made it into a function...

```
def click(button):
    pyautogui.mouseDown(button=button)
    pyautogui.mouseUp(button=button)
```

after which the following worked fine...

```
click('left')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got around this issue in my code:

```
if moveVar.get() == True:
                pyautogui.PAUSE = iCoor1[0]
                pyautogui.moveTo(x=xyCoor1[0], y=xyCoor2[0], duration=0.2, _pause=False)
                pyautogui.click(x=xyCoor1[0], y=xyCoor2[0], clicks=cCoor1[0], button='left')
            elif moveVar.get() == False:
                pyautogui.PAUSE = iCoor1[0]
                pyautogui.click(x=xyCoor1[0], y=xyCoor2[0], clicks=cCoor1[0], button='left')
```

Basically assigned a variable to the X and Y position and just used `moveTo` and then clicked.

for the variable you can simply do `x, y = pyautogui.position()` and then just assign the x & y value to the parameters, then call the variables again straight after you move, to click.